# Why is ethernet always associated with LAN?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I read this wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet which says Ethernet is used to connect to LAN,WAN and MAN but when i read Computer Networking books and other articles, they almost always associate Ethernet as a technology for LAN. Can someone explain to me? Iam terribly confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ethernet IS NOT always associated with LAN's.

Ethernet is a method of connecting devices so they can communicate, nothing more - it does not imply a LAN, MAN or WAN.  It does have a useful property of being able to allow communication between multiple devices.

Because of this property of being able to connect to multiple devices (along with WIFI, which is similar, but without the wires), Ethernet is useful in a LAN, which is why it is often associated with LAN's.   It was also first used in the role of connecting computers together (before the Internet was common)

Historically, because longer distance connections used the telephone infrastructure, technologies for transmitting over longer distances were done using telco protocols like Frame Relay, ATM, and more recently DSL.    That said, with fibre becoming a common method for transmitting data, and the merging of voice and data networks, Ethernet is increasingly being used by Telcos as well, which means its being used for WAN and MAN connections as well.

Comment: It may be worth noting also that Ethernet is associated with copper wires which significantly limits the distances between devices.  This can be overcome with fibre connections and fibre -> ethernet converters.